# How to perform drag and drop between two canvas in protractor

Tags: protractor

I have a canvas in which there is list of tables , i want to drag the tables 
from canvas to other canvas ...How can i achieve this in protractor.

Below is the code through which i tried.

```
// source table canvas
var canvas1 = element(by.xpath('.//*[@id="propertiesPanel"]/div/div/canvas')); 

browser.actions().mouseMove(element(by.xpath('.//[@id="propertiesPanel"]/div/div/canvas'))).perform();

canvas1.click();

//Target where i need to drop the table from canvas1
var canvas2 = element(by.xpath('.//*[@id="mappingDiagram"]/canvas'));

browser.actions().dragAndDrop(canvas1,canvas2).perform();

browser.driver.sleep(2000);
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: have you tried this `browser.actions().mouseMove(canvas1).mouseDown().mouseMove(canvas2).mouseUp().perform()` ?

Comment: Yes i tried that too but its also not working

Comment: Can someone please suggest and help in this!!